# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

I need your help please. I got an error about "Unsupported operand types"  but i didn't know about it. i've been trying search on google but i'm still can't fix it.

this my error title :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aplikasi_penjualan/admin/barang.php:28
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aplikasi_penjualan/admin/barang.php
>   on line 28

This is code at line 28 : `$halaman= ceil($jum / $per_hal);`

and this my code :

```html
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>  Data Barang</h3>
<button style="margin-bottom:20px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-info col-md-2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Tambah Barang</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<?php 
$periksa=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from barang where jumlah <=3");
while($q=mysqli_fetch_array($periksa)){ 
 if($q['jumlah']<=3){ 
  ?> 
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pesan_sedia').css("color","red");
    $('#pesan_sedia').append("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk'></span>");
   });
  </script>
  <?php
  echo "<div style='padding:5px' class='alert alert-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> Stok  <a style='color:red'>". $q['nama']."</a> yang tersisa sudah kurang dari 3 . silahkan pesan lagi !!</div>"; 
 }
}
?>
<?php 
$per_hal=10;
$jumlah_record=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) from barang");
$jum=mysqli_fetch_array($jumlah_record);
$halaman= ceil($jum / $per_hal);  //-----> THE ERROR IN HERE
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_hal;
?>
<div class="col-md-12">
 <table class="col-md-2">
  <tr>
   <td>Jumlah Record</td>  
   <td><?php echo $jum; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Jumlah Halaman</td> 
   <td><?php echo $halaman; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <a style="margin-bottom:10px" href="lap_barang.php" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></span>  Cetak</a>
</div>
<form action="cari_act.php" method="get">
 <div class="input-group col-md-5 col-md-offset-7">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari barang di sini .." aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="cari"> 
 </div>
</form>
<br/>
<table class="table table-hover">
 <tr>
  <th class="col-md-1">No</th>
  <th class="col-md-4">Nama Barang</th>
  <th class="col-md-3">Harga Jual</th>
  <th class="col-md-1">Jumlah</th>
  <!-- <th class="col-md-1">Sisa</th>   -->
  <th class="col-md-3">Opsi</th>
 </tr>
 <?php 
 if(isset($_GET['cari'])){
  $cari=mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['cari']);
  $brg=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from barang where nama like '$cari' or jenis like '$cari'");
 }else{
  $brg=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from barang limit $start, $per_hal");
 }
 $no=1;
 while($b=mysqli_fetch_array($brg)){

  ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $b['nama'] ?></td>
   <td>Rp.<?php echo number_format($b['harga']) ?>,-</td>
   <td><?php echo $b['jumlah'] ?></td>
   <td>
    <a href="det_barang.php?id=<?php echo $b['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Detail</a>
    <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $b['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
    <a onclick="if(confirm('Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data ini ??')){ location.href='hapus.php?id=<?php echo $b['id']; ?>' }" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</a>
   </td>
  </tr>  
  <?php 
 }
 ?>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4">Total Modal</td>
  <td>   
  <?php 
  
   $x=mysqli_query($conn, "select sum(modal) as total from barang"); 
   $xx=mysqli_fetch_array($x);   
   echo "<b> Rp.". number_format($xx['total']).",-</b>";  
  ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<ul class="pagination">   
   <?php 
   for($x=1;$x<=$halaman;$x++){
    ?>
    <li><a href="?page=<?php echo $x ?>"><?php echo $x ?></a></li>
    <?php
   }
   ?>      
  </ul>
<!-- modal input -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Tambah Barang Baru</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <form action="tmb_brg_act.php" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nama Barang</label>
      <input name="nama" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Barang ..">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Jenis</label>
      <input name="jenis" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Jenis Barang ..">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Suplier</label>
      <input name="suplier" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suplier ..">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Harga Modal</label>
      <input name="modal" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modal per unit">
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Harga Jual</label>
      <input name="harga" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Harga Jual per unit">
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Jumlah</label>
      <input name="jumlah" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Jumlah">
     </div>                 

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Simpan">
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



<?php 
include 'footer.php';

?>
```

I Hope you can help me.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If either of `$jum` or `$per_hal` is not a number you likely get an error, so are they both of type _number_?

Comment: @LGSon yes, they both is a number.

Comment: But `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array. So `$jum` must be an array.

Comment: `$jum = mysqli_fetch_array()` => it is not an int but an array. see the doc : http://php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 28, you fetch the result as an array (see the doc for [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) )

`$jum=mysqli_fetch_array($jumlah_record);` so `$jum` is array and cannot be divided

You can try this :

```
$per_hal=10;
$jumlah_record=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as number from barang");
$jum=mysqli_fetch_array($jumlah_record);
$halaman= ceil($jum['number'] / $per_hal);
```

`$halaman= ceil($jum / $per_hal);` was replaced by `$halaman= ceil($jum['number'] / $per_hal);` to get the value returned by the query

Comment: it's work.. alhamdulillah thank's.. but i get a new error. about conversion array to string.. at line 36.  this is the code at line 36 : <td><?php echo $jum; ?></td>         this is the error : Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aplikasi_penjualan/admin/barang.php on line 36
Array  ....... how to fix it?

Comment: `<td><?php echo $jum; ?>` should be `<td><?php echo $jum['number']; ?>`
or `<td><?php print_r($jum); ?>`